# VBA Code to Copy and Paste Excel Range into Outlook

Tags: css, vba, excel, outlook

I need to copy a range from an Excel file into Outlook, then send it as an email.  It needs to be embedded into the email itself.  I found this code which works great, with one exception:  It is centering the range in the middle of the "page" in outlook, and I need it to align to the left.

I am assuming this is done in HTML but I do not know that language.  Here is the code I am using:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub prcSendMail()
 Dim objOutlook As Object, objMail As Object

 Set objOutlook = CreateObject(Class:="Outlook.Application")
 Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)

 With objMail
     .To = "Mike.Marshall@worldpay.us"
     .Subject = "Hallo"
     .HTMLBody = fncRangeToHtml("Summary", "B2:G26")
     .Display 'zum testen
 '    .Send
 End With

 Set objMail = Nothing
 Set objOutlook = Nothing

 End Sub

 Private Function fncRangeToHtml( _
 strWorksheetName As String, _
 strRangeAddress As String) As String

 Dim objFilesytem As Object, objTextstream As Object, objShape As Shape
 Dim strFilename As String, strTempText As String
 Dim blnRangeContainsShapes As Boolean

 strFilename = Environ$("temp") & "\" & _
     Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy_h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

 ThisWorkbook.PublishObjects.Add( _
     SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
     Filename:=strFilename, _
     Sheet:=strWorksheetName, _
     Source:=strRangeAddress, _
     HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic).Publish True

 Set objFilesytem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 Set objTextstream = objFilesytem.GetFile(strFilename).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
 strTempText = objTextstream.ReadAll
 objTextstream.Close

 For Each objShape In Worksheets(strWorksheetName).Shapes
     If Not Intersect(objShape.TopLeftCell, Worksheets( _
         strWorksheetName).Range(strRangeAddress)) Is Nothing Then

         blnRangeContainsShapes = True
         Exit For

     End If
 Next

 If blnRangeContainsShapes Then _
     strTempText = fncConvertPictureToMail(strTempText, Worksheets(strWorksheetName))

 fncRangeToHtml = strTempText

 Set objTextstream = Nothing
 Set objFilesytem = Nothing

 Kill strFilename

 End Function

 Public Function fncConvertPictureToMail(strTempText As String, objWorksheet As Worksheet) As String

 Const HTM_START = "<link rel=File-List href="
 Const HTM_END = "/filelist.xml"

 Dim strTemp As String
 Dim lngPathLeft As Long

 lngPathLeft = InStr(1, strTempText, HTM_START)

 strTemp = Mid$(strTempText, lngPathLeft, InStr(lngPathLeft, strTempText, ">") - lngPathLeft)
 strTemp = Replace(strTemp, HTM_START & Chr$(34), "")
 strTemp = Replace(strTemp, HTM_END & Chr$(34), "")
 strTemp = strTemp & "/"

 strTempText = Replace(strTempText, strTemp, Environ$("temp") & "\" & strTemp)

 fncConvertPictureToMail = strTempText

 End Function
```

Is there some code to left align the range I am copying into Outlook?
I have W7 x64, Excel 2013 and Outlook 2013.
Thanks!

Comment: I don't use HTML but a simple search reveals that the HTML Tag to left align is <p align="left">text</p>.  Perhaps in the absence of anything else you could work this into you body text?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  I tried that with no luck.  This code is turning the data from excel that is copied into a private function.  I can't figure out where I would insert this code.

Comment: OK Mike I'm guessing here but in the absence of any expertise thus far, try concatenating "<p align="left"> plus the contents of your textstream plus "</p>" in the strTempText variable.  Can't help with the syntax but these HTML tags will need to be in quotes.  Prepare yourself you may have to write a little parser depending on the data being brought-in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this after your `objTextstream.Close`

```
strTempText = Replace(strTempText, "align=center x:publishsource=", "align=left x:publishsource=")
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
 With objMail
    .To = "Bofa@deeznutz.com"
    .cc = ""
    .Subject = "BR1 Summary for Adjustments +/- >$250"
    .HTMLBody = "<table width='100'><tr><td align=left>" + fncRangeToHtml("weekly adjustments report", Sheet1.UsedRange.Address) + "</td></tr></table>" & "<br>" & "<b>" & "<font size=4>" & "Adjustments +/- >$250" & "</font>" & "</b>" & fncRangeToHtml("Sheet1", Sheet2.UsedRange.Address)
```

VBA likes the quotes and the spaces. but in that last line of code you can either quote all of you HTML functions or break it up. but once you are finished using that like bold, you have to "/function" to end it before it likes the information. the & and + work the same.